# Ubuntu14.04 vs Ubuntu12.04 docker images

Tags: docker

I have some docker image based on ubuntu12.04 image. I want to migrate some of them to based on ubuntu14.04. But ubuntu14.04 image is almost 120 MB bigger than ubuntu12.04 image.

Anybody knows why and how reduce ubuntu14.04 image

running `docker images`

```
myregistry/ubuntu          14.04    xxx   xxx        225.4 MB
myregistry/ubuntu          12.04    xxx   xxx        103.9 MB
```

Comment: if you vote -1, can you write a comment why

Comment: Maybe if you tell us why do you want to do that? Did you try with docker diff command?

Comment: Understand that `docker diff` is for looking at changes within a running container, not to compare two images with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem I see is that you haven't shown us how you arrived at the images that you have. They are from a non-root registry ("myregistry") and you've omitted the hash from your copy/paste exercise.

When I download those images, here's what I see:

```
WineSoaked$ docker pull ubuntu:12.04
Pulling repository ubuntu
b45a6cbea6d1: Download complete
511136ea3c5a: Download complete
0b825e3a3d82: Download complete
3327dfd9dc7d: Download complete
4e284c9e0a9e: Download complete
ae9570f7a92a: Download complete
acc75c8f0e1d: Download complete

WineSoaked$ docker pull ubuntu:14.04
Pulling repository ubuntu
6b4e8a7373fe: Download complete
511136ea3c5a: Download complete
b18d0a2076a1: Download complete
67b66f26d423: Download complete
25c4824a5268: Download complete
8b1c48305638: Download complete
c900195dcbf3: Download complete

WineSoaked$ docker images
REPOSITORY      TAG             IMAGE ID        CREATED         VIRTUAL SIZE
ubuntu          14.04           6b4e8a7373fe    6 days ago      194.9 MB
ubuntu          12.04           b45a6cbea6d1    6 days ago      112.3 MB
```

You'll notice that the 2nd hash in each of those pulls is the same. That's the base image that these were built on. The rest have to do with the dockerfiles used to build them. Let's go have a look, shall we?

Here's the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/2b105575647a7e2030ff344d427c3920b89e17a9/precise/Dockerfile) for 12.04:

```
FROM scratch
ADD precise-core-amd64.tar.gz /

# a few minor docker-specific tweaks
# see https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap
RUN echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \
    && echo 'exit 101' >> /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \
    && chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \
    \
    && dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl \
    && cp -a /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d /sbin/initctl \
    && sed -i 's/^exit.*/exit 0/' /sbin/initctl \
    \
    && echo 'force-unsafe-io' > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/docker-apt-speedup \
    \
    && echo 'DPkg::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb    /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
    && echo 'APT::Update::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
    && echo 'Dir::Cache::pkgcache ""; Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
    \
    && echo 'Acquire::Languages "none";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-no-languages \
    \
    && echo 'Acquire::GzipIndexes "true"; Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order:: "gz";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-gzip-indexes

# delete all the apt list files since they're big and get stale quickly
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# this forces "apt-get update" in dependent images, which is also good

# enable the universe
RUN sed -i 's/^#\s*\(deb.*universe\)$/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

# upgrade packages for now, since the tarballs aren't updated frequently enough
RUN apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# overwrite this with 'CMD []' in a dependent Dockerfile
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Each of those commands in the Dockerfile corresponds to one of the hashes, which are intermediate images that comprise the AUFS file system. To wit:

- 511136ea3c5a corresponds to `FROM scratch`
- 0b825e3a3d82 corresponds to `ADD precise-core-amd64.tar.gz`...
- 3327dfd9dc7d goes with the epic-long `RUN`
- 4e284c9e0a9e goes with the `RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`
- ae9570f7a92a goes with the `RUN sed -i 's/^#\s*\(deb.*universe\)$/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`
- acc75c8f0e1d goes wit hthe `RUN apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`
  And b45a6cbea6d1 corresponds to the resulting image.

You can similarly break down the 14.04 image, based on its [Dockerfile](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/2b105575647a7e2030ff344d427c3920b89e17a9/trusty/Dockerfile):

```
FROM scratch
ADD trusty-core-amd64.tar.gz /

# a few minor docker-specific tweaks
# see https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap
RUN echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \
    && echo 'exit 101' >> /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \
    && chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d \
    \
    && dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl \
    && cp -a /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d /sbin/initctl \
    && sed -i 's/^exit.*/exit 0/' /sbin/initctl \
    \
    && echo 'force-unsafe-io' > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/docker-apt-speedup \
    \
    && echo 'DPkg::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
    && echo 'APT::Update::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
    && echo 'Dir::Cache::pkgcache ""; Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean \
    \
    && echo 'Acquire::Languages "none";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-no-languages \
    \
    && echo 'Acquire::GzipIndexes "true"; Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order:: "gz";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-gzip-indexes

# delete all the apt list files since they're big and get stale quickly
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# this forces "apt-get update" in dependent images, which is also good

# enable the universe
RUN sed -i 's/^#\s*\(deb.*universe\)$/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

# upgrade packages for now, since the tarballs aren't updated frequently enough
RUN apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# overwrite this with 'CMD []' in a dependent Dockerfile
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

So, looking at the Dockerfile, I would think that the major reason that 14.04 is larger is that the base tarball that they start from is larger. The [tarball](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/2b105575647a7e2030ff344d427c3920b89e17a9/precise/precise-core-amd64.tar.gz) for 12.04 is ~39MB, whereas the 14.04 [tarball](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/2b105575647a7e2030ff344d427c3920b89e17a9/trusty/trusty-core-amd64.tar.gz) is ~66MB. You could download and gunzip them to get their real sizes, but I think this gets you started on the road to understanding.

This can be confirmed using the [docker history](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#history) command:

```
$ docker history ubuntu:12.04
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE
b45a6cbea6d1        6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD [/bin/bash]               0 B
acc75c8f0e1d        6 days ago          /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get dist-upg   8.5 MB
ae9570f7a92a        6 days ago          /bin/sh -c sed -i 's/^#\s*\(deb.*universe\)$/   1.911 kB
4e284c9e0a9e        6 days ago          /bin/sh -c rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*          0 B
3327dfd9dc7d        6 days ago          /bin/sh -c echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/sbin/polic   156.2 kB
0b825e3a3d82        6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:f66a301611d5f2b8e4   103.7 MB
511136ea3c5a        16 months ago                                                       0 B

$ docker history ubuntu:14.04
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE
6b4e8a7373fe        6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD [/bin/bash]               0 B
c900195dcbf3        6 days ago          /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get dist-upg   2.178 MB
8b1c48305638        6 days ago          /bin/sh -c sed -i 's/^#\s*\(deb.*universe\)$/   1.895 kB
25c4824a5268        6 days ago          /bin/sh -c rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*          0 B
67b66f26d423        6 days ago          /bin/sh -c echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/sbin/polic   194.5 kB
b18d0a2076a1        6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:57743b1a50a2440168   192.6 MB
511136ea3c5a        16 months ago                                                       0 B
```

Comment: That was a particularly excellent edit @Thomas. Forgot completely about `docker history`